# ASUS TUF DASH F15 laptop issue

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

Few months ago, I bought my ASUS TUF DASH F15 gaming laptop. initially it had no problems but from past few days, I have been encountering 2 main problems.

1. Whenever I switch on my laptop, the lights are displayed and blinks like normal but the screen wont turn on, it just stays dark. I had to do force shut down. Been doing this whenever I get this problem, which is bad!
2. Whenever I connect my laptop for charging, the screen goes dark for 1-2 seconds and happens the same when the charger is removed. sometimes, the screen doesn't turn on, and unfortunately i had to do force shutdown.

If anyone has solutions for these problems, please answer. I am clueless now.

Comment: Is it still under warranty?

Comment: Yeah. It is...!

Comment: I would return it.